In nested gt table, how to line feed | change hyphen type
There is gt table Current Table ， how can I change to Wished Table1 and Wished Table2?
(There are separated question) .Refer to attached image. Thanks!
library(tidyverse)
library(gt)
    diamonds %>% head(5) %>% group_by(color) %>% 
      summarise(x=list(x),y=list(y)) %>% gt()



Unlist the columns before paste collapse:
Example input with list columns
library(gt)
library(dplyr)

d <- ggplot2::diamonds %>%
  head(5) %>% 
  group_by(color) %>% 
  summarise(x = list(x), y = list(y)) 
d
#   # A tibble: 3 × 3
#     color x         y        
#     <ord> <list>    <list>   
#   1 E     <dbl [3]> <dbl [3]>
#   2 I     <dbl [1]> <dbl [1]>
#   3 J     <dbl [1]> <dbl [1]>

Group by colour, then paste with collapse with "linebreak" and ungroup before gt:
# Table 1
d %>% 
  group_by(color) %>% 
  mutate(x = paste(unlist(x), collapse = "<br>"),
         y = paste(unlist(y), collapse = "<br>")) %>%
  ungroup() %>% 
  gt() %>% 
  fmt_markdown(columns = c(x, y))


Same again but collapse on "_":
# Table 2
d %>% 
  group_by(color) %>% 
  mutate(x = paste(unlist(x), collapse = "_"),
         y = paste(unlist(y), collapse = "_")) %>%
  ungroup() %>% 
  gt()



paste(y, collapse = "") can combine value with "".  Compart to the  original gt [summarise(x=list(x),y=list(y)) %>% gt()],   paste(y, collapse = "") can't automatically wrap content to next rows when I try to smaller the table by manual .  How can i keep this attribute and combine by "" ? Thanks!

@anderwyang try unlisting before pasting: paste(unlist(x), collapse = "_")

thanks for you help , but it's seems can't work

@anderwyang see edit, when input is a list column, we need to group, unlist, paste collapse, then ungroup and then gt.
